# Cannot remove contact us from navigation menu

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, contact-us

In Catalog -> Manage categories i have set "`Include in Navigation Menu`" No for contact us but still it displays in the menu. For other categories it works.

From the database level i went to `catalog_category_flat_store_1` and changed include in menu to 0 for the contact us entity id and it worked. Still if i refresh the indexes it keeps appearing in the menu. How can i set include in menu to 0 permanently for contact us?

========update===================

I disabled my 3rd party extension sm megamenu and still contact us is there.

Comment: reindex and clear cache and try again

Comment: I tried. Still doesn't work. I think a default value gets applied for **catalog_category_flat_store_1 include_in_menu** for that entity_id

Comment: Do you have any navigation extension?

Comment: I have something called sm megamenu. But i'm doing all the editing from manage categories.

Comment: either delete or rename var directory.

Comment: You need to change in megamenu extension

Comment: @prashant i checked in it also. But there was nothing called contact us in it

Comment: Are you sure it is coming from category? Please also check it is not coming from file.

Comment: @Prashant How can i check whether it's coming from a file?

Comment: Enable template path hint find template and check code is included in that file or not?

Comment: It is taken from the DB. Contact us in not hardcoded

Answer (score 1):

By default you can't have custom links in main navigation. You should remove this link from the additional module called SM Megamenu. Then try to clear your cache.

Comment: i checked in it also. But there was nothing called contact us in it

Answer (score 1):

For now i did a small code change to get it working.

`design/frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml` in about line 164 i changed the code to this. (Added a simple if condition wrapping draw item)

```
foreach ( $this->getStoreCategories() as $_category ){
    if($_category->getName() !== 'Contact Us'){
        echo $this->drawItem($_category);
    }
}
```